# Plasma Network widget crashed - no Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, plasma, widgets

I recently switched to Kubuntu and am kind of new to KDE. My plasma network widget refuses to respond and shows an error message which I don't understand. Copying the error message didn't work, so I have attached an image of it:

[image: Error message]

I'm on

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Yakkety Yak (development branch)
Release:        16.10
Codename:       yakkety
```

When I do

```
$ killall plasmashell
$ kstart plasmashell
```

I get something lots of these

```
<Unknown File>: QML Plasmoid: Cannot anchor to an item that isn't a parent or sibling.
```

Would be real cool if someone had a solution (internet currently only works through the wire ;))

Comment: same here, now using nm-applet from terminal.

Comment: Have you tried installing the Backports PPA? Usually the bug fixes have already been applied upstream, but not found their way back to stable.

Comment: 16.10 is in the very early development stage and is off-topic at this site.

Comment: Using nmcli (https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/nmcli.html) has done the trick insofar as I have a wifi connection at last.

Answer (score 0):

here what I did,
using kate in KDE , Made a **nm.sh** file with below code

```
#!/bin/bash  
nm-applet
```

Then , did *sudo chmod +x nm.sh* from terminal.
added this sh file to KDE startup.
Now on every reboot I get wifi / Network icon in tray.

[My screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbuz1.png)